# Fixed chat appointments

Tags: discussion, chat

I have just seen an ad for the writer's chat room, with writing exercise each Tuesday (actually I tried to snoop in but it looked quite unorganized). 
Do you think it's feasible to organize something similar here? I'm especially thinking about writing groups (as suggested sometimes in order to overcome writers blocks).

Some considerations:

1. the appointment should be quite defined, not just "on tuesday", but at least "the 1st and 3rd Tuesday of the month in the late morning" . So, the groups should be grouped by time zone (let's say by continent). This is just for practical purposes, of course if someone wants to work at 4 am is free to join the group of another continent
2. I am interested in academic writing, but I don't want to write here the details of my project or the draft of my papers. I can't think any better than some paper review, but I see that is too localized. So the rooms would be by time zone, by field and so on...
3. (this should be another questions) Can chats be deleted afterwards?

So, my original idea is not very practical. Anyway, I find the quality of the answers in the Academia.SE quite good , and I find enjoyable to read them even without having a specific question in mind. Hopefully also a (themed) chat group would have a similar quality. Any interest in this?

Comment: I see now a similar question http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/532/better-use-of-the-chat-room-discussion-groups-proposal?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The idea is good, it just needs community support. Once it's been decided that we should do it, [we can definitely help with the advertising](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/73). I had written a whole bit about how we should try themed chats, but after consideration, that seems needlessly specific; the best goal (to me) would be to simply set up a time where the community can ask questions in chat and have an open-ended discussion.

Thoughts?

Comment: A once a month open house could be fun. It would have to be advertised well, and we should get some commitments from hi-rep users to show up.

Comment: @Suresh that's exactly what I had in mind, when I asked my question (linked above) but the interest appeared to be rather weak. It would be cool to try it out at least