# Why Academia.SE does not have events on chat rooms?

Tags: discussion, chat

Looking at the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)'s [events section](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=events&sort=active&nohide=true&host=academia.stackexchange.com), we can see that there are many events available for other stack exchange websites; none of which are for Academia.

Is there any reason (or possibly kind of policy) for not having chatroom events for [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) or is this because the website does not need such events? Can we have some events for this website too? What advantages or disadvantages would it be for the website by having events for this website?

Answer (score 4):

It's been suggested before [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/532/better-use-of-the-chat-room-discussion-groups-proposal) and [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/849/fixed-chat-appointments).

Nobody seemed interested enough to organize it at the time.

As has been stated there, if someone goes to the trouble of organizing an event and demonstrates that there is community interest, a mod can create the "event" in the software.

Comment: People are not interested and it is asked previously. So downvote my question and vote it to be closed.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: Those questions are about specific types of event and thus not necessarily the same. Also, you can vote to close your own question, if that reflects your opinion. Finally, just being a duplicate is no reason for a downvote.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft If those questions are not necessarily related to this one, why this user is posting them as examples to this suggestion? I think that if they are irrelevant, the user only posts them to say that my suggestions are *always useless*. Also, this person most of the times tries to stop me on this site, that close comment was due to her previous behaviour towards my activities on the site.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent This is the answer to the question "Why Academia.SE does not have events on chat rooms?", not a comment on the premise of the question. The reason we don't have events is because although events have been suggested, the suggestions have never yet matured into fruition.

Comment: If anyone has any interest in chat room events, please post a new question here in meta with a suggestion! We're  definitely open to hosting these if there's interest!