# What about directing advice-seeking questions immediately to chat?

Tags: feature-request

The Q&A format of academia.SE is limited when it comes to questions where someone just needs advice or a brief therapy session from a formless elder in the ivory tower.  Yet many people (especially those new to SE and unfamiliar with the format) ask away anyway. Then they either get closed or get a flurry of attention and opinions that are probably not really what they were looking for in the first place.

I've been wondering if there's a better way to process such questions without overwhelming or shutting down a real person in real distress.  Already there are mechanisms that suggest if someone's question might be a duplicate or opinion-based when someone is typing a question.  This is great.  But would it possible to also refer the question-asker to chat?  Such a feature might even help with question qualitiy in the long run, because the question-asker would have a chance to work out the kinks in chat and then, if they still deem it necessary, post a question.

This question is related: [Better use of the chat room: Discussion groups proposal?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/532/better-use-of-the-chat-room-discussion-groups-proposal). In fact, I think my proposal would help achieve the OP's goal of utilizing chat more.

Comment: I don't know whether the SE staff can implement such request or not (and whether they'd be willing to implement it), but take into account two things: i) to use the chatroom one should have at least 20 rep, and most of the users that are in distress, and have trouble asking questions, are newcomers with 1 rep; ii) our chat is not particularly populated and the chances of getting an answer there may be thin.

Comment: I think the current process works to a great extent, i.e. we use comments to tell the OP what to improve and how to improve their questions. SE allows the asker, even 1 rep point to write comment under their own questions. I think this is better than the chat room. If the comment thread is too long, a user can open a chat room or the OP can flag the mod to move the comments into a chat room to continue to chat. As far as I can see, it ain't broken yet, no need to fix.

Comment: Also, my personal experience (I actually did the kind of things you suggest) is that  many users got the useful info/solution/suggestions, they just left. Never improve the question, never come back. After a while, the chat room would freeze. No one would read the contents. That's it. After a few such instances, I stopped doing that.

Comment: @scaaahu Bummer, but makes sense.